# How can I change the Icon of an Applet?

Tags: java, applet, icons

unfortunately my first game extends applet rather than JApplet, but it's finished now, so I won't go back and change it (Unless this is an easy thing to do? I have no idea.)

I am about to export my Applet, and I want to be able to run it like an application from the desktop. For this to be effective, I want to add my own icon, rather than have the typical steaming coffee cup. Also when I click it, I want it to appear in the Dock/Taskbar (Yes I'm looking to make this cross-platform) with the icon as well.

Does anyone know how to do this? Here is what I've tried so far:

```
public class Resources {
    static Image iconimage;
    URL url;
   static StartingPoint sp;         //StartingPoint is my main class

    public Resources(StartingPoint sp) {
        try{
            url = sp.getDocumentBase();
        }catch (Exception e){   
        }
        iconimage = sp.getImage(url, "Images/iconimage.png");

    this.sp = sp;   
    }
}
```

---

```
public class StartingPoint extends Applet{
    Image icon = Resources.iconimage;
    URL url;

    public void init() {
        setIconImage(icon);
    }
}
```

I get the error- "The method setIconImage(Image) is undefined for the type StartingPoint"

Could someone please explain a fix for the error or a different method of setting the icon? Thanks!

Comment: why you cannot change the code? In any way you are going to change it, is not it?

Comment: Launch the applet (free floating) using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It provides functionality to install desktop shortcuts and menu items for apps., with an icon if specified.